# PhpStorm + GIT on virtual machine

Tags: git, virtual-machine, phpstorm, sshfs

Here is my workstation setup:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- A few virtual machines (one with nginx, another with apache, etc). I use virtual box for this.
- PhpStorm as my IDE

I mounted the virtual machines in some locations with `sshfs` (`sshfs root@test.com:/var/www/ ~/vm/`), so I see the files in PhpStorm. Since only the files in `/var/www/` are visible here, PhpStorm doesn't know that GIT is installed.

Is it possible to make the GIT from my VM to work with PhpStorm? If it is, how do I do this? I haven't found anything about this anywhere, and I need to manually write the path to the GIT executable to get it to work (which I can't/don't know how to access since it's on a VM).

Comment: You need local git to use version control from PhpStorm.

Comment: Damn, thanks. I suppose it's the same for Xcode right? Post it as an answer and I'll mark it is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use git integration in PhpStorm you need to have a local installation of the version control client on the host machine where you run the IDE so that IDE can locate and run it.